# Text file is locked for openning when running the script but I can open it manually

Tags: powershell, locking, streamwriter

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
do{
    $Error[0]= $null
    $StreamWrite = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($PathToTextFile,$true,[system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
    
 }while ($Error[0] -ne $null)
$StreamWrite.WriteLine("$TimeStamp")
$StreamWrite.Close()
$StreamWrite.Dispose()
```

I run this through Task Scheduler on specific events, but it never gets out of the loop as it raises the error of the file is open by another process.
But when I run it line by line, there's no problem. I can also open the text file in Windows browser.
What am I missing?

Comment: `$Error[0] = $null` will either result in an error or be ignored. Use `try`/`catch`/`finally` if you want to capture and suppress any exceptions raised by the `[StreamWriter]::new` call, and make sure to call `$StreamWrite.Dispose()` in the `finally` block to release the lock

Comment: Why not simply using the native PowerShell [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet?

Comment: Also note that the problem may not be one of locking, but one of permissions, for instance. `catch` and log the exception to determine the actual cause. (As an aside: while `$Error[0] = $null` does work, it's better not to overwrite existing items in the `$Error` collection).

Comment: @ Mathias R. Jessen- Yes, I didn't mention that I have $StreamWrite.Close() and $StreamWrite.Dispose()  at the end of my script. I've just edited my OP.

Comment: @iRon- I've tried "Write-Output "$TimeStamp" | out-file -FilePath $PathToTextFile -Append -Force" but this seems to overlook whether the file is already opened or not.

Comment: So `Try/ Catch/Finally` is for handling errors, but I'm looking for the opposite, something that will run only when there's no error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try opening the FileStream with FileShare Read, Write permissions. There are many examples of that in this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as a good solution for thread-safe StreamWrite and encoding:

```
do{
    $Error.Clear()  
    
    $FileStream= [System.IO.FileStream]::new($PathToTextFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Append,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Write,[IO.FileShare]::None)
    $StreamWrite = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($FileStream,[system.Text.Encoding]::Unicode)
    
 }while ($Error.Count -gt 0)
```